# How to make a Constructor without parameters?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

I have to write a program that has a **constructor without parameters**. I created another short program as an example to show what I do not understand.
So I have a class with the main-method:

```
public class Dog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    CharacteristicsOfTheDog Dog1 = new CharacteristicsOfTheDog(20, 40);
        System.out.println(Dog1.toString());

    }
}
```

Now implemented another class:

```
public class CharacteristicsOfTheDog {

    int size = 0;
    int kilogram = 0;


    public CharacteristicsOfTheDog(/*int size, int kilogram*/) {
        // this.size = size;
        // this.kilogram = kilogram;
    }

    public double getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public double getKilogram() {
        return kilogram;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "The Dog is " + getSize() + " cm and " + getKilogram() + " kg";

    }
}
```

In the class "CharacteristicsOfTheDog" in "public CharacteristicsOfTheDog()" I removed the parameters by commenting them out. So the Problem is: if I remove the parameters the program does not work:/ but my task is to do this without the parameters (as far as I understood). Can someone help me please?

Comment: In your constructor without parameters, give default values to `size` and `kilogram`. In the  `CharacteristicsOfTheDog` class, add setters for `size` and `kilogram`. In the main method, create `Dog1` using the constructor without parameters, and pass the 20 and 40 using the setters.

Comment: The task seems: to introduce & use "setters"!(?) (..or to use "class body" initializer `int size = 20, kilogram = 40;`), ..your "empty constructor" is ok/super, but `size` and `kilogram` are de facto "immutable"

Comment: And what 'does not work' mean in your question?  Does the output not match what you're expecting?  Is there an error/exception?  That information would help us figure out the direction to take our answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your no-arg constructor and then add setters for your properties:

```
public class CharacteristicsOfTheDog {

    int size = 0;
    int kilogram = 0;

    public CharacteristicsOfTheDog() {
    }

    public void setSize(int size){
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void setKilogram(int kilogram){
        this.kilogram = kilogram;
    }
}
```

In your other class, call:

```
CharacteristicsOfTheDog dog1 = new CharacteristicsOfTheDog();
dog.setSize(20);
dog.setKilogram(40);
```

As a suggestion, the naming of your class as CharacteristicsOfTheDog is rather literal and stating the obvious. Properties and methods of a class are what describes the characteristics of a class in terms of it's properties and behavior. If you just name your class Dog, that would be perfect. No need to state the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `CharacteristicsOfTheDog` is a subclass or you have a constructor with parameters, you don't need an empty constructor.  Just omit it. The following works just fine.

If the parent class has a constructor with arguments, then the parent class will need an explicit empty constructor, but the following should still work.

```
CharacteristicsOfTheDog cotd = new CharacteristicsOfTheDog();
   cotd.setKilogram(100);
}

class CharacteristicsOfTheDog {
    int size = 0;
    int kilogram = 0;


    public void setSize(int size){
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void setKilogram(int kilogram){
        this.kilogram = kilogram;
    }
}
```

Depending on your use case, you might want to make the Characteristics class an interface and implement it.